Cross-Category Filtering Logic with AND/OR in GridBuilder Plugin in Wordpress with Elementor
I'm using the GridBuilder plugin for WordPress to create a filtering form with these categories and subcategories:
Age: Puppy, Young Adult, Adult, Senior
Size: Small, Medium, Big
Gender: Female, Male
A person should be able to choose multiple criteria.
The problem I'm facing is that the facet currently applies non-excludent logic across all selections, so it shows results that don’t match all the criteria from the main categories. For example, if I select "Female" and "Puppy + Young Adult" the form still show male puppies or young adults just because I selected those age options, ignoring the gender filtering.
How can I configure GridBuilder to fix that?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
I've tried setting the facet both for AND and OR logic, but none helped me achieve the desired results.
For example:
With OR logic, if I select Female + Puppy/Young adult dogs, I see male puppies and male young adult dogs, which I didn´t want to see.
With AND logic, as soon as I click a subcategory (Puppy, for example), I can't choose any other subcategory, and I wanted to be able to do that.

Well I guess I ansewered my own question! I should have created multiple facets, instead of a single facet linked to categories that had subcategories.
